# How to remove url's from string

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have many rows in one column similar to the string below. On python I have run the code to remove

, <a, href=, and the url itself using this code

```
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'\s*https?://\S+(\s+|$)', ' ').str.strip()
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'\s*href=//\S+(\s+|$)', ' ').str.strip()
```

However, the output continues to remain the same. Please advise.

```
<p>On 4 May 2019, <a href="https://www.ft.com/content/26b6d24e-6d77-11e9-a9a5-351eeaef6d84">The Financial Times</a> (FT) reported that Huawei is planning to build a '400-person chip research and development factory' outside Cambridge. Planned to be operational by 2021, the factory will include an R&amp;D centre and will be built on a 550-acre site reportedly purchased by Huawei in 2018 for &pound;37.5 million. A Huawei spokesperson quoted in the FT article cited Huawei's long-term collaboration with Cambridge University, which includes a five-year, &pound;25 million research partnership with BT, which launched a joint research group at the University of Cambridge. Read more about that partnership on this <a href="https://chinatechmap.aspi.org.au/#/map/marker-1024">map.</a></p>
<p>In 2020 it was reported that the Huawei research and development center <a href="https://archive.ph/wip/OrAd3">received approval by a local council</a> despite the nation&rsquo;s ongoing security concerns around the Chinese company.</p>
<p>Chinese state media later <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20190505143025/https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201905/05/WS5ccecddfa3104842260b9df9.html">reported that</a> Huawei's expansion in Cambridge 'is part of a five-year, &pound;3 billion investment plan for the UK that [Huawei] announced alongside [then] British Prime Minister Theresa May' in February 2018.</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you specify how your column is and what would be the desired output? It's a bit difficult to understand the problem like this.

Comment: infrastructure_type_id
6 | Manufacturing facility                                                                                          
 Text |column  "<p>On 4 May 2019, <a href=""https://www.ft.com/content/26b6d24e-6d77-11e9-a9a5-351eeaef6d84"">The

Comment: Now it's even more complicated!

Comment: Sorry! Just added image in question! Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to replace the following html tags:

```
<p>, <a, href=, and the url
```

**Code**

```
df['text'] = df.text.replace(regex = {r'<p>': ' ', r'</p>': '', r'<a.*?\/a>': '+'})
```

**Explanation**

Regex dictionary does the following substitutions

- <p>               replaced by ' '
- <a href = .../a>  replaced by '+'
- </p>              replaced by ''

**Example**

Create Data

```
s = '''<p>On 4 May 2019, <a href="https://www.ft.com/content/26b6d24e-6d77-11e9-a9a5-351eeaef6d84">The Financial Times</a> (FT) reported that Huawei is planning to build a '400-person chip research and development factory' outside Cambridge. Planned to be operational by 2021, the factory will include an R&amp;D centre and will be built on a 550-acre site reportedly purchased by Huawei in 2018 for &pound;37.5 million. A Huawei spokesperson quoted in the FT article cited Huawei's long-term collaboration with Cambridge University, which includes a five-year, &pound;25 million research partnership with BT, which launched a joint research group at the University of Cambridge. Read more about that partnership on this <a href="https://chinatechmap.aspi.org.au/#/map/marker-1024">map.</a></p>
<p>In 2020 it was reported that the Huawei research and development center <a href="https://archive.ph/wip/OrAd3">received approval by a local council</a> despite the nation&rsquo;s ongoing security concerns around the Chinese company.</p>
<p>Chinese state media later <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20190505143025/https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201905/05/WS5ccecddfa3104842260b9df9.html">reported that</a> Huawei's expansion in Cambridge 'is part of a five-year, &pound;3 billion investment plan for the UK that [Huawei] announced alongside [then] British Prime Minister Theresa May' in February 2018.</p>'''
data = {'text':s.split('\n')}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.text[0])   # show first row pre-replacement

 # Perform replacements
df['text'] = df.text.replace(regex = {r'<p>': ' ', r'</p>': '', r'<a.*?\/a>': '+'})

print(df.text[0])   # show first row post replacement
```

**Output**

*The first row only*

*Before replacement*

> On 4 May 2019, [The Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/26b6d24e-6d77-11e9-a9a5-351eeaef6d84) (FT) reported that Huawei is planning to build a
> '400-person chip research and development factory' outside Cambridge.
> Planned to be operational by 2021, the factory will include an R&D
> centre and will be built on a 550-acre site reportedly purchased by
> Huawei in 2018 for £37.5 million. A Huawei spokesperson quoted
> in the FT article cited Huawei's long-term collaboration with
> Cambridge University, which includes a five-year, £25 million
> research partnership with BT, which launched a joint research group at
> the University of Cambridge. Read more about that partnership on this
> [map.](https://chinatechmap.aspi.org.au/#/map/marker-1024)

*Post Replacement*

> On 4 May 2019, + (FT) reported that Huawei is planning to build a
> '400-person chip research and development factory' outside Cambridge.
> Planned to be operational by 2021, the factory will include an R&D
> centre and will be built on a 550-acre site reportedly purchased by
> Huawei in 2018 for £37.5 million. A Huawei spokesperson quoted
> in the FT article cited Huawei's long-term collaboration with
> Cambridge University, which includes a five-year, £25 million
> research partnership with BT, which launched a joint research group at
> the University of Cambridge. Read more about that partnership on this + ​

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex pattern instead:

`<a href=(.*?)">`

I successfully tested this using your test string on [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

[image: regex101 test]

#### Full code:

```
import re

df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'<a href=(.*?)">', "").str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your regex is quite right. Try:

`df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'<a href=\".*?\">', ' ').str.strip()`
`df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'</a>', ' ').str.strip()`